# Add message to popup message box C# noob question

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, error-handling

How can I add message to popup text box:

```
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Interaction.MsgBox(Conversion.ErrorToString(), MsgBoxStyle.Critical, null);
        }
```

Comment: Did you come over to C# from VB6?  Ditch that Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace, its trash :)

Comment: please be sure to come back and choose the most helpful answer by clicking on the big checkmark next to it.

Comment: @Allen I have, I must say I tend to agree

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [MessageBox class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.aspx).

```
catch (Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show(
         Conversion.ErrorToString(),  // Caption
         "Error:",                    // Title displayed
         MessageBoxButtons.OK,        // Only show OK button
         MessageBoxIcon.Error);       // Show error icon (similar to Critical)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
MessageBox.Show("text", "caption", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
```

Also, I see you tagged the post C#.  If you're using C#, don't use anything in the [Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.aspx) (which is where `Interaction` lives)

> The Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace
>   contains types that support the Visual
>   Basic Runtime in Visual Basic.

Answer (score 0):

Some more examples:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/messagebox-show

Answer (score 0):

You already are, with `Conversion.ErrorToString()`. If you want a custom message, just pass a string of your choosing as the first argument instead. The third argument (which you have `null`), can be used to pass a string for the title if you want.